# Set selected option

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got option select. How to set as var selected select automaticly?

```
<option>
<select>1</select>
<select>2</select>
</option>
```

E.g. I manually select option 1, and it automaticly is

> `<select selected="selected">1</select>`

**EDIT** I found out.

```
<select id="sel">
    <option value="1">aa</option>
    <option value="2">bb</option>
    <option value="3">cc</option>
</select>

$("#sel").change(function(){
   alert($(this).val())
});
```

Comment: I don't understand your problem exactly, but you got it wrong. `select` is the outside tag, and inside should be `option`s.

Comment: Didn't even notice that, that's right, your code is messed up!

Comment: think you need to clarify what is it you want to do!

Comment: "User can choose "2" and option "2" have to automaticly set to 'selected'", quoting you, this happens already, whichever option you select, is the value "selected" when the form is submitted.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$("#myOption").val("1");
```

Comment: I've got form and I need to automaticly pass the data. User can choose "2" and option "2" have to automaticly set to "selected"

Answer (score 1):

your code should be

```
<select>
    <option selected="selected">1</option>
    <option>2</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Yes - but I need this to set automaticly when i select it. I've got form. I need to pass value by ajax.

Comment: then use the jQuery mentioned in other answers $("#myOption").val("1"); wrap it in a $(document).ready()

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @creminsn!! and For that to get value
Try this

```
var val;
$('#selectID').click(function(){
val=$('#selectID option:selected').val();
});
```

val will give you the selected val.And if you need text you can do

```
$('#selectID option:selected').text();
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite see what your issue is, however im getting the idea from what you've written that you want to submit the form upon the user selecting an option from the dropdown?

In which case u need [JQuery](http://jquery.com) to implement a listener (`.live()`) on the dropdown which will fire an event, in your case you want to submit the form (i think) so perhaps use `.post()` if you do want to use ajax.

look these up on the jQuery site.